# BigQuery Navigation Function - filtering inside PERCENTILE_CONT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
WITH transactions AS (
  SELECT
    "cust1" AS customer_id,
    5 AS amount,
    DATE "2020-01-01" AS date
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust1", 1000, DATE "2020-03-05",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust1", 10, DATE "2020-04-01",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust1", 18, DATE "2020-04-03",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust1", 48, DATE "2020-04-05",

  UNION ALL SELECT "cust2", 63, DATE "2020-01-05",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust2", 3, DATE "2020-03-01",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust2", 27, DATE "2020-03-05"
)

SELECT
  customer_id,
  amount,
  date,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(amount, 0.5) OVER (
    PARTITION BY
      customer_id
    -- the following ORDER BY and window frame clause are not proper syntax
    -- but this is essentially what I would like to get at
    ORDER BY
      date DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN 30 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS median_last_month
FROM transactions
WHERE
  customer_id = "cust1"
```

Working with BigQuery standard SQL here. I'm looking to calculate a row's median (see example query). Furthermore, I want the median to be calculated only on transactions that happened in the last month relative to the current row.

My expected results would be

```
"cust1", 5, "2020-01-01", 5
"cust1", 1000, "2020-03-05", 1000
"cust1", 10, "2020-04-01", 505
"cust1", 18, "2020-04-03", 18
"cust1", 48, "2020-04-05", 33
```

I see that for several other navigation functions in BigQuery you can specify a "window frame clause", but not with `PERCENTILE_CONT`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what YOU mean by "last month related to the current row.  Is that supposed to be 30 days?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is correct. take for example the transaction for "cust1" with an amount of 48. The PERCENTILE_CONT function should essentially only look at transactions for the same customer_id which happened in the preceding 30 days of the current row being considered. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since percentile_cont function doesn't accept a window definition, you can use array_agg to create an array within the defined range, and then you can calculate median.

To define a 30 days window, I converted date to Unix timestamp in seconds, and used a range window using seconds, again.

```
WITH transactions AS (
  SELECT
    "cust1" AS customer_id,
    5 AS amount,
    DATE "2020-01-01" AS date
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust1", 1000, DATE "2020-03-05",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust1", 10, DATE "2020-04-01",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust1", 18, DATE "2020-04-03",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust1", 48, DATE "2020-04-05",

  UNION ALL SELECT "cust2", 63, DATE "2020-01-05",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust2", 3, DATE "2020-03-01",
  UNION ALL SELECT "cust2", 27, DATE "2020-03-05"
),
transactions_amount_agg AS
(
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    amount,
    date,
    ARRAY_AGG(amount) OVER (
      PARTITION BY
        customer_id
      ORDER BY
        UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date))
      RANGE BETWEEN 2592000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW -- 2592000 = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 
    ) AS last_month_values
  FROM transactions
)
select *, 
  (
    SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(val, 0.5) OVER ()
    FROM UNNEST(last_month_values) as val
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS median_last_month
from transactions_amount_agg
```

Comment: spot on, thanks! :) I haven't used ARRAY_AGG or UNNEST before, will have to keep these in mind for future problems

Comment: one small comment, I think the `ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date))` should in fact be `ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date)) DESC`

Comment: If you make it DESC, it will take the future 30 days. Do you want the previous 30 days or the next 30 days from that specific day?

Comment: ah yes, spoke before validating this, you're indeed right (window frame clauses are mind-bending)

Answer (score 1):

`PERCENTILE_CONT()` doesn't do what you want -- alas.  It is neither an aggregation function, nor does it allow a window frame.

One method is rather brute-force -- a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.customer_id, t.amount, t.date,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(tprev.amount, 0.5) OVER (
         PARTITION BY t.customer_id, t.amount, t.date
       ) AS median_last_month
FROM transactions t JOIN
     transactions tprev
     ON tprev.customer_id = t.customer_id AND
        tprev.date <= t.date AND
        tprev.date > date_add(t.date, interval -1 month)
WHERE t.customer_id = 'cust1';
```

This method allows you to clearly specify the "month".  Because this can vary from date-to-date, I can't think of a simple method for handling this.

Comment: I'll give this a try, my query processes ~150GB of data, might be too inefficient but worth a try.

Comment: Fair point on the month varying (in terms of number of days). I should have been more specific, but I only need latest 30 days for now!

Comment: @JoeyOrlando . . . How much worse is this than the other solution?